What breakers or switches are really needed on this solar setup?
I asked a question whether with DC breakers does polarity really matter?, that caught fire in the direction of whether at all to use those breakers or any breakers for that matter. The suspicion is that inserting breakers inserts a risk of arcs and fire.
So here is what I have and what breakers I thought to use:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Each solar panel (PV1, PV2, and PV3) of 330 W has 48 V across, so in series I go in with 144 V. So at 330 W each panel we have 990 W total, at 144 W, makes 6.875 A. So I chose a 10 A DC breaker for SW1.
The battery is 48 V, 100 Ah, 4.8 kWh. If we charge the battery with those 990 W from the panels, we have here 20.625 A. But the charge controllers max output power on the battery side is 100 A, therefore I have put a 125 A breaker for SW2.
The inverter is a 48 V, 3 kW continuous and 6 kW peek power, so the breaker SW3 here should actually be 125 V as well. But I had chosen 50 A for now.
I should probably use the 50 A breaker for SW2 and the 125 A breaker for SW3 for now, since the panels I have currently would never be able to output more than 21 A.
But then the question came up, why have any of those breakers at all?
Clearly the wiring should be chosen to handle the maximum output power of any source. And when that is the case, no wire overload can happen, therefore, no breaker is needed for protection.
What about switching and isolating components for maintenance? Seems like disconnecting the panels at once is a good idea. Not so clear is the question whether SW2 and SW3 are needed. I can just turn off the inverter to stop drawing power from the battery. And if the PV supply is off the charge controller won't supply any power to the battery.
The reason not to have breakers is to avoid a situation where the breaker trips or is being switched off under load and causing an arc and a subsequent fire if it's a bad breaker or installed the wrong way.
My question is whether the arc issue is really a concern at 48 V even if the battery is giving off 125 A to the inverter at a moment of peak load?
The only high voltage switching is in SW1, 144 V with 6.825 A, that is an arcing concern, yes? Strangely that breaker has no +/- markings, but something still says line should come from above with + on the left. Why would it say that if the markings on the item do not say any such thing?
PS: I am asking this question from an engineering perspective, let's not get hung up over "code" that are subject to jurisdiction.
Here is a good text, Discussion Paper on Correct Wiring of Double Pole DC Breakers, speaking how this should generally work, specifically how the symbol's +/- markings stand for source + and source - (not load). So I think I figured out reliably how they should be wired.
The only problem is the leg from charge controller to battery. Because here we have a limited charge current of 21 A, but if the terminals of this charge controller were ever to short out, the massive overcurrent would be sourced from the battery, so I think that breaker should be put in reverse. Or better be replaced with a known non-polar DC breaker.

Which country are you in? Not sure if there are local wiring codes which give rules about what is required.

@ChesterGillon I am asking this question from an engineering perspective, let's not get hung up over "code" that are subject to jurisdiction.


Why have breakers at all?

Are you trying to build an arc welder or a power distribution system?
Breakers give you the capability to easily disconnect the power sources when you need to do maintenance or in an emergency.
Without the breakers you will get some approximation of an arc welder if there is current flowing when you try to disconnect.

The reason not to have breakers is to avoid a situation where the breaker trips or is being switched off under load and causing an arc and a subsequent fire if it's a bad breaker or installed the wrong way.

Install the right breakers.  it it can't safely be turned off under load it's not the right breaker. (see arc welder above)

Clearly the wiring should be chosen to handle the maximum output power of any source. And when that is the case, no wire overload can happen, therefore, no breaker is needed for protection.

What happens when there's a short circuit that doesn't evaporate?
Perhaps your wires can handle 3KA, but your battery is not going to like that.
Also  many devices need a breaker before them to limit the fault current the device can be supplied.
Things break, breakers are there to limit the damage they cause when that happens.
